# Find most related post in many to many relationship

Tags: entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I have a many to many relationship as following in code first:

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

modelBuilder.Entity<Post>().HasMany(c => c.Tags).WithMany(a => a.Posts);
```

If i have a `Post` with its `Tags` , how i can get most related posts by considering `Tags`.

Comment: is it the _related_ in a sense, by given a `Post` you want to find the related `Post`s? can't you slap some similarity computation on it?

Answer (score 0):

Several ways. My suggestion:

```
var postsAndTagCounts = context.Posts
    .Select(p  => new {
        PostId = p.Id,
        TagCount = p.Tags.Count()
    })
    .OrderByDescending(p => p.Tags.Count())
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you will need to define how *related* should be..

The easiest way would be simply checking the post that share the most tags. We need to do this for the given post and the rest of the posts. I won't dwell much on the theory, your query will be looked like this at least:

```
IQueryable<Post> posts = context.Posts.Where(x => x.Id != currentPost.Id)
                                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Tags.Count(y => currentPost.Tags.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id)));
```

Where `currentPost` is an instance of `Post` that we want to retrieve its related `Post`s. The calculation is done on the `x.Tags.Count(y => currentPost.Tags.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id))` part. It counts how many tags it share with `currentPost`.

A bit more sophisticated, you could use [Jaccard Similarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaccard_index). It simply divide the number of same tags in a `Post` pair with the total `Tag`s of the pair.

```
int currentPostTagsCount = currentPost.Tags.Count();
IQueryable<Post> posts = context.Posts.Where(x => x.Id != currentPost.Id)
                                      .OrderByDescending(x => x.Tags.Count(y => currentPost.Tags.Any(z => z.Id == y.Id))
                                                              / (currentPostTagsCount + x.Tags.Count()));
```

**Disclaimer:** I have not tested the query, take it with grain and salt - i will edit if i had time to test and it does not work.